# Is there any way to know when a tab in the browser is covered by a window?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, visibility, visibilitychange

TL;DR: *I'm working on a Chrome extension where I need to increase a count only when a tab is visible and not covered by another window. Is there any way to detect this?*

---

I've tried using the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API), but here's the problem with it:

Imagine I have two windows docked side by side. My focus is on tab 'X' from window 'A'. But, to the side, I also have tab 'Y' open in the foreground of window 'B'.

If I check `document.hidden` for tab 'Y' at that time, it will resolve to `false`, which is what I'd want. However, if I then expand window 'A' to cover the full screen and leave window 'B' open behind it and not minimized, `document.hidden` for tab 'Y' will still equal `false` even though, from a user-vision perspective, that tab is completely invisible.

Adding event listeners to the `blur` and `focus` events doesn't help either because `blur` is fired whenever the document it's added to loses focus, which would work fine for the scenario where I have window 'A' covering the entire screen , but isn't suitable for the scenario where I have window 'A' and 'B' side by side. In that case, the 'blur' event would be fired when tab 'Y' loses focus even though tab 'Y' is technically visible to anyone who is looking at the screen.

---

The outcome I need looks like this:

1. Tab 'Y' is in the foreground of a non-minimized window AND not covered by another window:
   `increaseCount() // regardless of whether the tab is focused or not`
2. Tab 'Y' is in the foreground of a non-minimized window BUT is covered by another window such that its contents wouldn't be visible to any human observer:
   `// don't increase count`

---

Is there any way to detect this?

Comment: IntersectionObserver v2 tells that via `isVisible` property since Chrome 74.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer @wOxxOm. I've read through the API docs and ran some experiments myself but, unfortunately, it seems the IntersectionObserver v2 is uncapable of detecting this. The observer can only detect when a target element is visible within a container root element. It can't detect when the tab itself or any of its elements are covered by, let's say, a tab from another window.

Comment: Well then you'll have to write your own low-level implementation as a separate utility and launch it via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: That will do it, thank you @wOxxOm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no reliable way to detect this.

In fact, it's my understanding that Chrome might not even know if the content is covered.  Consider a case like Windows, where ever since Windows Vista and Aero, the application window is always drawn and intercepted by the window manager.  The underlying application is always drawing to a virtual space.  Other complications include windows that may cover the browser window but may not be totally blocking it.  Without knowing the content, the browser doesn't really know if the content is covered.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Brad. Do you know if it is possible to detect this with software running directly on the OS (Windows or Mac)? For simplicity, if my aim was only to detect when a non-minimized and fully-expanded window is covered by another fully-expanded and not minimized window, could an application running outside of the browser detect this?

Comment: I can't speak for OS X, but native software can detect this on Windows, yes.  The OS is sandboxing applications more and more these days though, so there may be some caveats or permissions required.

Comment: Great to know; I'll look into it. Thank you for the pointer!

Comment: Chrome 87 [tracks the real occlusion](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Di4DiGwHamIgLYjaOpripOJQinUquUuyxuiim2-WUIs/view) internally but doesn't expose the info to JS, apparently. The [linked doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tPuJE0Vws7oskjjqrawNfMkwFtGxyHV33yQagiplVfY/edit) says the state is [will be?] updated through the Page Visibility API available for JS though.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for that information!!  This sounds like an impending nightmare.  :-(  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=668690